# why does my time function not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, time

today date is correct but time i get time 30 minute ahead for sample 
at now India time is 10:30 and i got the 11:00 pm

date is working but why time is wrong.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
$dates = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time());
echo $dates;
?>
```

Comment: Its working http://codepad.org/wZ6gabNG

Comment: Your code is correct, check the server time.

Comment: Your server time (clock) may be faster than the clock your looking at

Comment: Thanx @YogeshSuthar i tested this code in my local computer this give me wrong date and time but after tested in server i got right date and time.

Comment: thnax bansi and Andre this is working now. actually i tested in local computer so i got wrong time.

Comment: Try using `Asia/Kolkata`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to give a timestamp

Try this

```
$dates = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes -

1. Your local computer clock is set wrong
2. You have an out-of-date timezone definition file that incorrectly defines Asia/Calcutta, or does not define it at all.

I have run this successfully here for your timezone (Linux RHEL6, package tzdata-2011d-1.el6.noarch )